# ghost field not unghosting

Tags: javascript, html, forms, post, drop-down-menu

So I have a small issue: I created a drop down menu and a text field beside it. Only one selection in the drop down menu should cause the text field to unghost. All other selections should cause the text field to lock, so to speak.

The code below:

```
</td> <td><select name="employee_type" onchange="document.getElementById('otherField').disabled=(this.value == 1, 2)">
<option value=0>Temporary</option>
<option value=1>Regular</option>
<option value=2>Special Access User</option>
```

```
<input id="otherField" type="text" name="date_expires_input" value="YYYY/MM/DD" style="color:#aaa; font-style:italic;" onclick="this.value=''; this.style.color='#000'; this.style.fontStyle='normal';" />
        </tr>
```

does do that. However, if the user was to select "Temporary" and *then* change his mind to select "Regular", the field would remain ghosted. Anyone know why?

Comment: Can you provide an example using jsfiddle perhaps? Also, unless this is something I'm unfamiliar with, you have a syntax problem in your onchange script. `this.value == 1, 2` is not valid. Did you mean `this.value == 1 || this.value == 2`?

Comment: You're right, that was it! Thanks taz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about

```
<select name="employee_type" onchange="document.getElementById('otherField').disabled=(this.value != 0)">
```

? it's the other way round, so to say... you cannot say `this.value == 1, 2`, you would then have to say `this.value == 1 || this.value == 2`

Answer (score 1):

your condition should be

```
document.getElementById('otherField').disabled = (this.value == 1 || this.value == 2)
```

Comment: Yeah that was totally it. Thanks very much :-)